# Flutter: Formatting DateTime in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

How to format flutter DateTime
as 10th Oct 2020

tried

```
String date = DateFormat("dd, mm, y").format (date.utc());//10 October 2020
```

Comment: Per [`DateFormat`'s documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html), the specifier for an abbreviated month is `MMM`. (Your example is also wrong: you use `mm`, but that would give you the minute.) `package:intl` doesn't have a way to print "10th" instead of "10", but you could use something like [`package:humanizer`'](https://pub.dev/packages/humanizer)s [`OrdinalNumericalTransformation`](https://pub.dev/documentation/humanizer/latest/humanizer/OrdinalNumericalTransformation-class.html) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Jiffy package from here ==> https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy.

this is an example of formatting DateTime:

```
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';

void main() {
  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();


  String result = Jiffy(currentTime).format('MMM do yy');
  print(result);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy)
Just simply add the do date pattern. See below

```
Jiffy([2020, 10, 10]).format("do MMM yyyy"); //10th Oct 2020
```

You can also add your DateTime object

```
Jiffy(DateTime(2020, 10, 10)).format("do MMM yyyy"); //10th Oct 2020
```